# Calculating dates in CouchDB

Tags: date, couchdb

I have some documents in CouchDB that contains a value called expire. e.g.:

```
"expire": "2014-11-23T16:01:00+00:00".
```

I'm trying create a view that displays all documents between now and X number of days and years until the "expire" value. The X (in days/years) needs to be passed in via the query URL.

I've been struggling with this for a while now and any examples/pointers would be much appreciated.

Carlskii

Comment: You'll either need to use [`startkey` and `endkey`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) directly to the view, or use a [`_list`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List?highlight=%28%5C_list%29#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later) function that does "post-query processing".

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you've attempted in order to tell you why it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to resolve this! The solution was to use the javascript function. e.g.

```
Date.parse(doc.expire)
```

I can then use this to determine what documents (based on date) get returned by my view.